# How can I deal with it? I want to show $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I simply cannot deal with it. how to start....
the problem follows :
Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent with $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $P(Z=1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$.
Let $Y=X \times Z$. Prove:

(a) $Y \sim N(0,1)$
(b) $P(|X|=|Y|)=1$
(c) $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
(d) $Cov(X,Y)=0$

I can prove (a) ,(b) but I got stuck at (c).
Could you let me start?!

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are very much _dependent_ random variables since if we know that one of them has value $\alpha$, then the other is equally likely to have value $\pm\alpha$: independence would require that the conditional distribution of the other does not depend at all on the value taken on by the one. Are you sure you typed in (c) correctly?

Comment: The goal of the exercise is to show that covariance zero does not imply independence. Hence (c) is definitely: "Show that X and Y are **not** independent."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are not independant. Let $I = [-1,1]$. Then $P(X \in I, Y \in I) = P(X \in I)$, since $X = \pm Y$. And of course, $P(Y \in I) = P(X \in I)$ is not zero.